# "index exceeds matrix dimensions" error matlab

Tags: matlab

I have developed this function with :

```
Point = [2,11]
```

and

```
vector_X = [1,9;7,8;2,7;4,7;6,7;8,7;5,6;5,5;2,3;4,3;5,3;6,3;1,2;5,1];
```

and

```
MinPts = 3;
```

function :

```
function Distance = MutualReachabilityDistance(Point,vector_X,MinPts)

M1 = pdist2(Point,vector_X);

[~, dist1] = knnsearch(Point, vector_X, 'k', MinPts+1);
core1 = max(dist1).*ones(1,length(vector_X(:,1)));


for i=1:length(vector_X(:,1))
    [~, dist2] = knnsearch(vector_X(i,:), vector_X, 'k', MinPts+1);
    core_X(1,i) = max(dist2);
end

Distance = max(M1,core1);
Distance = max(Distance,core_X);
```

I get this error with this line :

```
test = MutualReachabilityDistance(Point,vector_X,MinPts);
```

Best regards

Comment: Please try and run the function as a script to see what line gives you the error.

Comment: Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in clustering (line 77)
Distance = MutualReachabilityDistance(Point,vector_X,MinPts);

Comment: Replace `length(vector_X(:,1))` with `size(vector_X,1)`, just for readability.

Comment: I do not receive an error when I run your code with the given input. Nevertheless, I think your error message is not complete as matlab should give you also the line inside the `MutualReachabilityDistance` function which results in the error. Please add all relevant information to your question or try using the matlab debugger or your favorite search engine to solve the problem yourself. A lot of question exists about _“index exceeds matrix dimensions”_.

Answer (score 1):

I do not get any error from your code. The error message may be due to test variable which is the repetition of same number. To avoid it change the last two lines of the function as below

```
function Distance = MutualReachabilityDistance(Point,vector_X,MinPts)
    M1 = pdist2(Point,vector_X);
    [~, dist1] = knnsearch(Point, vector_X, 'k', MinPts+1);
    core1 = max(dist1).*ones(1,length(vector_X(:,1)));

    for i=1:length(vector_X(:,1))
        [~, dist2] = knnsearch(vector_X(i,:), vector_X, 'k', MinPts+1);

        core_X(1,i) = max(dist2);
    end

    Distance = max(M1,core1);
    Distance = max(Distance,core_X);
end
```